# Apply certain CSS "inside div"

Tags: html, css

```css
ul.b {
  list-style-type: square;
  margin-left: 60px
}

div.form {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <ul class="b">
    <li>
      DUMMY TEXT
    </li>
   <li>
        DUMMY TEXT
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The code above works fine , but is there any method that can "pre-set" the CSS in the div, which means that does you do not need to declare `"class=b"` in `<ul>` to be able to get the style?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.form ul` (all ul tag inside div have class .form) or `.form > ul` (only direct child ul inside div has class .form) as

```
.form > ul{
 list-style-type: square;
  margin-left: 60px
}
```

```html
<style>

.form > ul{
 list-style-type: square;
  margin-left: 60px
}

div.form {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

</style>
</style>
<div class="form">
<ul>
  <li>
    DUMMY TEXT
  </li>
 <li>
      DUMMY TEXT
  </li>
<ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. as follows:

```
<style>

.form {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
.form ul {
  list-style-type: square;
  margin-left: 60px
}
</style>

<div class="form">
<ul>
  <li>
    DUMMY TEXT
  </li>
 <li>
      DUMMY TEXT
  </li>
</ul> <!-- here you didn't close the ul -->
</div>
```